# alter table is not working in db2

Tags: database, db2

I'm trying drop an to drop a column in DB2 getting error like below.

```
 ALTER TABLE Table_name DROP COLUMN Temporary;



 SQL State: 57014
    Vendor Code: -952
    Message: [SQL0952] Processing of the SQL statement ended. Reason code 10. Cause . . . . . : The SQL operation was ended before normal completion. The reason code is 10. Reason codes and their meanings are: 1 -- An SQLCancel API request has been processed, for example from ODBC. 2 -- SQL processing was ended by sending an exception. 3 -- Abnormal termination. 4 -- Activation group termination. 5 -- Reclaim activation group or reclaim resources. 6 -- Process termination. 7 -- An EXIT function was called. 8 -- Unhandled exception. 9 -- A Long Jump was processed. 10 -- A cancel reply to an inquiry message was received. 11 -- Open Database File Exit Program (QIBM_QDB_OPEN). 0 -- Unknown cause. Recovery . . . : If the reason code is 1, a client request was made to cancel SQL processing. For all other reason codes, see previous messages to determine why SQL processing was ended.
```

Comment: That error means that the client connection was interrupted. It is not a database error or wrong SQL. You need to provide more details, including the table schema, Db2 version and correct error.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504548/db2-400-drop-column

Comment: Thanks Rahul.after running below command.it's started working in iSeries Navigator CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC('CHGJOB INQMSGRPY(*SYSRPYL)');